# compare 2 gridviews and update gvl from gv2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to compare oldgridview with newgridview and update newgridview from oldgridview usinf asp.net and c#

can any one support me

thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: how to compare 2 gridviews and update old one with existing one on button click?

Comment: add what you've done so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable src1 = gv1.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataTable src2 = gv2.DataSource as DataTable;
        int index1 = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row1 in src1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row2 in src2.Rows)
        {
            int index2 = 0;
            bool duplicateRow  = true;
            for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row1.ItemArray.Count(); cellIndex++)
            {
                if (!row1.ItemArray[cellIndex].Equals (row2.ItemArray[cellIndex].ToString()))
                {
                    duplicateRow  = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (duplicateRow)
            {
                gv1.Rows[index1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor  = Color.Red;
            }

            index2++;
        }
        index1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it an answer of ur question , or this is have tried so far ?? . if it is not answer, Edit your question via adding this code, and leave the answer section empty.